# How can I create array of lines in this case?

Tags: bash

Given a file so that in any line can be more than one word, and exists a single space between any word to other, for example:

> a a a a
>   b b b b
>   c c
>   d d
>   a a a a

How can I create array so that in the cell number `i` will be the line number `i` , but WITHOUT DUPLICATES BETWEEN THE ELEMENTS IN THE ARRAY !

In according to the file above, we will need create this array:
`Array[0]="a a a a"` , `Array[1]="b b b b"` , `Array[2]="c c"` , `Array[3]=d d`.

(The name of the file pass to the script as argument).

---

I know how to create array that will contain all the lines. Something like that:

```
Array=()
while read line; do
Array=("${Array[@]}" "${line}")
done < $1
```

But how can I pass to the `while read..` the sorting (and uniq) output of the file?

Comment: `.... done < <(sort "$1")` and similar. Good luck.

Comment: If a line is skipped because it was a duplicate, should there be a gap in the array indices, or should the line be removed before the line number to array index mapping happens? What would the array look like if you had line `e e` at the end in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `done < <(sort "$1" | uniq)` in place of `done < $1`.

The `<()` syntax creates a file-like object from a subshell to execute a separate set of commands.

Comment: This won't map "line number to cell number" as per question, but it seems the OP is happy with it, so...

Comment: Side note: you can replace `sort | uniq` with `sort -u` and avoid one subshell.